# Ternary Operator does not work inside an Object

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-operator

Ternary operator does not work inside Objects. its show false out despite condition being true. I tried it with function and it works just fine.

```js
'use strict';

const person = {
  age: 31,
  statement: this.age >= 30 ? 'true output' : 'false output'
};

console.log(person.statement)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in this example, `this` refers to `window` object
use it as below:

```js
const person = {
  age: 31,
  statement: person.age >= 30 ? 'true output' : 'false output'
};
```

if you want to use `this`, you have to use it within a function:

```js
const person = {
  age: 31,
  statement: function(){
    return this.age >= 30 ? 'true output' : 'false output'
  }
};
```

then call it as function:

```js
person.statement(); //result true output
```